# Proper policy on using electrical plug outlets in Toronto Pearson International Airport

Tags: airports, regulations, power, yyz

I tend to be always on long layovers, delayed or even cancelled flights from Toronto. So I like to do work on my laptop and most of the times, I am already out of charge from the previous flight. Are there any policies on what plugs I can and cannot use in Toronto Pearson International Airport?

For example, I know that in some coffee shops, students bring power strips, can I use one in an airport? A next example, plug outlets near the entrances of gates.

Comment: @hippietrail http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/633/revisions better ?

Answer (score 17):

My personal view is that it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission.  Most people working there won't give a rat's *** about you using a powerpoint, save perhaps for security, but at most they'll just tell you to move along.

I do a lot of travel, airports, bus stations, train stations, and my eye is always looking subconciously for power sockets now ;)  I've happily recharged in anywhere there happens to be a power socket (save on a kazakhstan train where the power socket wasn't working), and the most comment I've had is "do you know if there are any others?" or "can I share the socket?" from other travelers :)

Comment: Bringing a power strip makes you very popular among fellow travellers. I happened to have one when staying overnight at CPH, and at least three persons came over asking to use it at various times during the night (there are only two or three outlets in the terminals, not very easy to discover). I even managed to secure an invitation for a visit in Lisbon, which I made good for some months later.

Answer (score 14):

I've used the power in a lot of airports, including YYZ, and never been told not to or even glared at. A few tips:

- They have to vaccuum the place. Look for power and you'll see it
- In the gate area the plugs are often in the floor. You might have to pry up a cover. Again, no-one seems to mind. When they're not in the floor, they're in the concrete columns
- In Terminal 3 (not the Air Canada-dominated Terminal 1) there are plugs in the benches - look just underneath them
- Air Canada has power on most of its planes in economy now. If you're flying out of YYZ anyway, keep that in mind when choosing your carrier
- Plenty of plugs in the lounges, too
- Bring a little plug-cube (like your grandmother might use) - I got one at Canadian Tire for a dollar. Perfect for sharing that plug with others. I approach strangers who are using the only plug and ask if I can unplug them, plug in the cube, and then share. I always get a yes.

Answer (score 11):

I would say you should be fine as long as you're not in the way.  Plug in at the boarding area rather than a walkway, and I don't think anyone will bug you.  I haven't used the outlets at YYZ, but I've been there a few times and generally security doesn't bother anyone who's not harming anything.

Comment: incidentally, YYZ is the most made-up sounding airport code, always grin when I see that :)

Answer (score 2):

One concern they may have is the potential for people to trip over. I assume the best way to avoid that being a problem is to have your laptop near the outlet.